# How can I fix this positive list haskell code?

Tags: list, haskell

Write a function that multiplies all the positive elements in a list!
I tried to make it, but I need help because it is not working. Can anybody help me what is the problem and how can I fix it?

```
positive :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> a
positive x
  | x> 0 = x * y
  | otherwise = Nothing

Example:
positive [1..10] == 3628800
positive ([1..10] ++ [-2, -5, -6]) == 3628800
positive [3, 5, 66, -8, -4, 5, 6, 93, -4567, 56] == 154677600
```

Comment: You can not use `x > 0`, since `x` is a list.

Comment: You already have a function that can multiply all the values in a list together (`product`). Just write a second function that removes non-positive numbers from a list, then compose them. `positive = product . removeNonpostive`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not use `x > 0`, since `x` is a list. You can pattern match on `(x:xs)` for a non-empty list with `x` the first item, and `xs` the remaining items; and on `[]` for the empty list.

So the function should look like:

```
positive :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> a
positive [] = …    -- (1)
positive (x:xs)
  | x> 0 = …       -- (2)
  | otherwise = …  -- (3)
```

Where you need to fill in the `…` parts. The first part (1) should return a result in case of an empty list. The second (2) has a positive number `x`, and should recurse on the rest of the list `xs` and multiply the two together. Finally, the third case should recurse on the rest of the list `xs`, since `x` is less than or equal to zero.

Comment: Like this :                                                                                                                         
positive :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> a
positive [] = 0 
positive (x:xs)
  | x > 0 =  x * positive xs 
  | otherwise = positive xs  ? Something is wrong because I get 0 in all cases. Any idea to correct ?

Comment: @mano19: the product of an empty list is not `0`.

Comment: You know, empty stuffs are always tricky.. I guess 0 is still a relatively new invention.